# ¿Cómo muestro la animación del reloj de arena correctamente?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Cuando intento hacer que funcione siempre algo falla al querer ver un reloj de arena y la arena no cae correctamente, además de ello suele salir otro problema cuando corro el código el cual es que no termina de formarse el reloj de arena, en cambio simplemente queda como una bolita por la cual las partículas caen hacia un lado en vez de esparcirse por todo el reloj. Además de ello intenté crear otro modelo de reloj terminando en el mismo problema. ¿Es posible que haya una variable mal puesta?

```js
// JavaScript para la generación de partículas de arena
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const sandClock = document.querySelector('.sand-clock');

  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const particle = document.createElement('div');
    particle.classList.add('sand-particle');
    particle.style.animationDelay = `${Math.random() * 5}s`;
    sandClock.appendChild(particle);
  }
});
```

```css
/* Estilos para el reloj de arena */

.sand-clock {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

.sand-particle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: gold;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: fall 5s linear infinite;
  left: 50%;
}

@keyframes fall {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-200px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(200px);
  }
}


/* Estilos adicionales */

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}
```

```html
<h1>Fuera de servicio</h1>
<div class="sand-clock">
  <div class="sand-particle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Gbianchi se refiere a que tu pregunta es confusa, no especifica que es lo que te falla o que es lo que esperas, toda esa informacion necesaria esta en los links que el coloco, es importante que pongas esa informacion en tu pregunta porque de lo contrario no sabemos que es lo que te esta fallando o que es lo que no te funciona

Comment: ¿Buscás hacer [esto](https://www.uplabs.com/posts/css-only-animated-sandwatch-loader-icons) pero con CSS y JS en lugar de CSS puro?

Answer (score -1):

```js
// JavaScript para la generación de partículas de arena
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const sandClock = document.querySelector('.sand-clock');

  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const particle = document.createElement('div');
    particle.classList.add('sand-particle');
    particle.style.animationDelay = `${Math.random() * 5}s`;
    sandClock.appendChild(particle);
  }
});
```

```css
/* Estilos para el reloj de arena */

.sand-clock {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #378;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  
}

.sand-particle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: gold;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: fall 5s linear infinite;
  left: 50%;
}

@keyframes fall {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-200px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(200px);
  }
}


/* Estilos adicionales */

body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: #f6f;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color 1.3s ease;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}
```

```html
<h1>cargando</h1>
<div class="sand-clock">
  <div class="sand-particle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo revisar el artículo [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/) que te explicará como hacer mejores respuestas y de paso mejorar tus puntos de reputación en este sitio.

Comment: Hola thomasito, gracias por responder a la pregunta. Las publicaciones que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad porque no suelen ser de ayuda para los usuarios. Es mejor añadir una pequeña descripción de lo que hace el código y cómo soluciona el problema. Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información (y así ganarás tu primera medalla en el sitio)